# Stream live to udp-rtsp or http protocols with GStreamer

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

Stream a video file or m3u8 file from the internet via udp or rtsp with ffmpeg. I can watch from players like VLC player. As in the examples below. Can I do the same with gstreamer?

Ubuntu: 22.04.1 LTS
gstream: GStreamer 1.20.4

ffmpeg -re -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +genpts -i "https://www.blabla.net/tv/tv_360p.m3u8" -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -fps_mode cfr -c:v copy -b:v 1050k -maxrate 1300K -bufsize 2500K -strict experimental -tune zerolatency -f "rtsp" "rtsp://192.168.1.111:8554/rtsp_stream?pkt_size=1316"

ffmpeg -re -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +genpts -i "https://www.blabla.net/tv/tv_360p.m3u8" -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -fps_mode cfr -c:v copy -b:v 1050k -maxrate 1300K -bufsize 2500K -strict experimental -tune zerolatency -f "mpegts" "udp://225.100.5.1:5000?pkt_size=1316"

ffmpeg -re -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +genpts -i "video.mp4" -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -fps_mode cfr -c:v copy -b:v 1050k -maxrate 1300K -bufsize 2500K -strict experimental -tune zerolatency -f "mpegts" "udp://225.100.5.1:5000?pkt_size=1316"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play you can use playbin and play the stream. The bin will take care of demuxing and sending it to your sinks.

Here is an example.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/634cd01c-6822-4630-8444-8dd6279f94c6/CaminandesLlamaDrama4K.ism/manifest\(format\=m3u8-aapl\)"
```